# passing php array to json for web service

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have develop an webservice for the iphone and when i do simple`echo` or `print_r` it show me the result but when i pass it into the `json` and `encode` it that gives null but if i `var_dump` the `json array` it will display the data can any one tell me why is it happening ? does it bcox of text length ? i am sharing my code also please have a look

```
$sql= "SELECT `post_content` FROM `wp_posts` where `id`=16 AND `post_status`='publish'
ORDER BY `wp_posts`.`post_title` ASC";

$result= mysqli_query($con,$sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error().$sql);
$json= array(); 
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$json['emp_info'][]=$row;
var_dump($json);
echo json_encode($json);
```

Please help but dont down vote i search before posting the question but none of that worked for me

Comment: What PHP version do you have?

Comment: 5.3.13 @SergeiBeregov